# Need to color terminal's output produced with print command Term::ANSIColor

Tags: perl, terminal

Here is what I have:

```
use Term::ANSIColor;
print "Blah!".color("green");
```

The output is

```
Test←[32m
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminal program you are using does not support the ECMA-48 color escape codes. So it does not give them any special treatment, and instead outputs the characters as-is.

What you are missing: a terminal that does. xterm, libvte, putty, are just a few to name that do.

Comment: Is there a workaround? I know system("color A"); works but for the entire screen.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~jlmorel/Win32-Console-ANSI-1.04/lib/Win32/Console/ANSI.pm

Comment: Can't install modules on this machine? Win32/Console/ANSI is not available, need alternatives...

Comment: http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JLMOREL/Win32-Console-ANSI-1.04/lib/Win32/Console/ANSI.pm
Copy and paste? Also, you can install modules. Always. Give me a minute, gotta find that link.
EDIT: Here you go: http://www.shadowcat.co.uk/blog/matt-s-trout/but-i-cant-use-cpan/

Comment: @seaworthy, there's no solution that doesn't depend on an XS module or an external program to manage the console.

Comment: @Hugmeir, copy & paste is useless here, because the real work is done by the XS code that takes over the console and interprets the escape codes.

Comment: yeh, copy paste didn't work, neither did CPAN {i always have problems with it}, ppm though worked fine... :) thanks for help

Comment: @cjm, yeah, my bad, didn't even bother checking the full distribution or the dependencies. "Download and make" makes better sense, eh?
@seaworthy, from that comment, it seems like you are using ActiveState Perl, which doesn't come with it's own C compiler. How about getting Strawberry Perl? Installing modules becomes a joyful breeze: perl -MCPAN -e "install Win32::Console::ANSI"

Answer (score 1):

Are you on Windows? I'm fairly certain that the Windows shell isn't compliant with the color codes used by the module.

Actually, it says so right there on the module's documentation.

> Note that not all displays are ISO 6429-compliant, or even X3.64-compliant (or are even attempting to be so). This module will not work as expected on displays that do not honor these escape sequences, such as cmd.exe, 4nt.exe, and command.com under either Windows NT or Windows 2000. They may just be ignored, or they may display as an ESC character followed by some apparent garbage.

EDIT:
An addendum to my comment:

```
C:\>perl -MWin32::Console::ANSI -MTerm::ANSIColor -e "print color(\"green\"), 'test', color(\"reset\");"
```

Works just fine on Windows XP, Perl 5.12.1, so there's your workaround.

Comment: No go, I think you have the module installed.